# Get date from timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql, psql

The query below returns a table with data type time stamp without time zone. How do I format this query so it removes the timestamp and just save the date?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('dbname=mydb', 'select startdate from study') as t1(start timestamp without time zone);
```

Output:

```
|-----------start-------|   
|  2012-03-19 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-04-26 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-05-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-06-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-07-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-08-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-02-07 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-04-26 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-09-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2012-12-01 00:00:00  |  
|  2013-11-11 00:00:00  |  
+-----------------------+
```

What I'm looking for:

```
|------start---|
|  2012-03-19  |  
|  2012-04-26  |  
|  2012-05-01  |  
|  2012-06-01  |  
|  2012-07-01  |  
|  2012-08-01  |  
|  2012-02-07  |  
|  2012-04-26  |  
|  2012-09-01  |  
|  2012-12-01  |  
|  2013-11-11  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast *timestamp* field to *date*, following ways can be apply

```
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('dbname=bhkpps', 'select begins::date from study') as t1(start date);
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('dbname=bhkpps', 'select begins from study') as t1(start date);
```

or

```
SELECT start::date
FROM dblink('dbname=mydb', 'select begins from study') as t1(start timestamp without time zone);
```